# Why do errors occur?

Tags: python

Simply source

```
class page:
    pages = "/.././ewcwe/../qds/./qwd/qwf/qwd/../../../sad/qwd/../sad/qwd/sad/.././../../../../bbs/./board.php?bo_table=humor&wr_id=195?los=09&qwe=2&"

    def __init__(self):
        self.normalize()

    def normalize(self):
        for j in range(1, len(self.pages)):
            if self.pages[j-1] != "." and self.pages[j] == "." and self.pages[j+1] == "/":
                self.pages = self.pages[:j] + self.pages[j+2:]
                print self.pages

        print self.pages

index = page()
```

There's no problem but error occurs.
Why do errors occur?

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what the errors are?

Comment: ... and get the formatting correct.

Comment: Yes, because we don't know if you got the formatting wrong when posting here or in your code (and thus the errors).

Comment: If errors occur, than there is a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import os
os.path.normpath(pages)
```

normalizes your path and returns:

```
'/bbs/board.php?bo_table=humor&wr_id=195?los=09&qwe=2&'
```

You don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You will be getting an error because your index will eventually be going out of range.

You iterate from index 1 till the end of the string:

```
for j in range(1, len(self.pages)):
```

But then go on to index beyond that:

```
self.pages[j+1]
```

and

```
self.pages[j+2]
```